# Как дeбажить java-приложение на деплое?

Tags: java, отладка, deploy

Есть java-приложение, которое развернуто на сервере Apache tomcat, во время работы возникает проблема при загрузке файла на сервер. Уже знаю, как скачать логи при помощи filezila, но разобраться с проблемой так и не удалось, так как не могу точно определить где возникает ошибка. Вероятнее всего уже есть какой-то реализованное решение, чтобы отлаживать уже задеплоенные проекты. Подскажите как это правильно делается, потому что раньше никогда не имел дело с этим. Буду рад любым советам

Comment: Хорошо что не на проде :) Вы можете дебажить развернутое приложение через ту же intellij idea, но для этого нужно сделать некоторые действия - https://habr.com/ru/articles/513520/

Comment: @AlekseiGaile Большое спасибо за Ваш ответ, отличная статья, но хочу уточнить, сервер развернут не мной, а во вкладке application server от меня требуется tomcat home и tomcat base directory. Не совсем понимаю, откуда я должен взять эти данные, если у меня нет понимания файловой системы развернутого проекта. Или имеется ввиду, что я должен сам накатить tomcat на свой компьютер и указать ему путь, но возникает вопрос - зачем, я же не у себя на компьютере хочу дебажить, а на сервере. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем я не прав?

Comment: Отлаживать на деплое не надо, разве что если деплой сломался. Удаленная отладка вообще существует, но для этого надо подключиться с дебаггером на удаленный сервер, а это может не работает. Лучше всего подключиться к удалённому серверу через ssh ну и там дебажить.